# Fastest pre-packaged key-value pair search

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, boost, stl

I'd like to implement the following data structure in c++ (pseudo code):

```
Map<Integer, Integer>    // Key->Value pairs

Map.put(1,6);
Map.put(2,5);
Map.put(6,89);
Map.put(7,23);
... etc ...

Map.get(2) .... returns 5
```

In other words, given pairs of integers, where one of them is a look-up key, what is the fastest library implementation that lets me retrieve the Value from one of the Keys? The opposite search of Value->Key is not required.

The size of this map would likely be on the order of 10 000 elements.

I assume a binary tree search will yield the fastest lookup time? 
Is std:map the best tool to use? Does boost present any alternatives?

Comment: By pre-packaged I believe OP means some existing implementation of the data-structure. Not that the key values are known before hand. Just commenting so others don't mis-interpret it like I did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an `unordered_map` (hashmap) or `map` (binary tree) - Likely `unordered_map` will be faster. Also, if your key value is limited to 10000, a `vector<int>` will guarantee constant-time lookup - Use a "magic" value for vector elements that should be "not present".

`unordered_map` is a part of TR1 and c++0x - it is *not* standard in c++03. Many implementations support it though. Boost also has an `unordered_map`.

`map` and `vector` are both standard.

- `map` corresponds to java `TreeMap`
- `unordered_map` corresponds to java `HashMap`
- `vector` corresponds to java `ArrayList`

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Are these template classes that are part of the standard library, or are they part of boost?

Comment: These are standard template classes, but `unordered_map` is new and may or may not be available on your configuration.

Comment: misunderstanding, the Value is not limited to the integer 10,000 , but is limited to 10,000 unique 'values'. When in general would a hashmap be superior to a binary tree?

Comment: The only correct answer to that is, it depends. In most cases, if you don't need to access elements in order, a hash table is faster. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table goes into details.

Comment: @J T: hash tables need a hash function: these need to be complex enough to effectively spray the values pretty evenly across the hash buckets.  How hard that will be depends on the properties of your keys, but for ints it's probably achievable with a handful of basic arithmetic operations.  The, there's a tradeoff between more buckets (wasting space, reducing cache effectiveness) and less (more collisions, necessitating rehashing and/or displacement and/or linear search).  But, even though you probably want a few times more buckets than you have values, the memory's contiguous.